# Make browser give a custom made note when re-visiting websites

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

Lately I've been browsing through hundreds of ads on a website similar to craigslist.

Due to the similarities of the ads, I have to read through almost the entire ad to decide if it's interesting or not. For the same reason, I've been reading many of the same ads many and more times even though I figured out the first time it wasn't interesting.

I want to write a note saying: "Not interesting, due to xxx", "Very interesting" etc. that will appear the next time I enter that ad. Is this possible to achieve in a simple way or would I have to create my very own add-on? (I can use whatever browser that makes this possible (except Safari)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several Firefox extensions that can do this. *FloatNotes* works well.

1.) **Install [FloatNotes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/floatnotes/) extension**

[image: add to firefox]

2.) **Restart Firefox**

3.) **(Optional) Configure settings `Tools -> FloatNotes -> Preferences`**

[image: preferences]

4.) **On any webpage, <kbd>right-click</kbd> then `Create note...`**

[image: context menu]

5.) **Type your note, then click outside the note to save**

[image: add note]

6.) **Close the tab/window/firefox**

7.) **Return to the same page later and the note will be there and in the same spot!**
[image: view note]

---

If you prefer Chrome, then *Note Anywhere* is a good choice.

1.) **Install [Note Anywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/note-anywhere/bohahkiiknkelflnjjlipnaeapefmjbh)**

[image: note anywhere]

2.) **Select note button to create a new note**

[image: toolbar]

3.) **Type your note, then click outside the note to save**

[image: not interesting]

4.) **Close the tab/window/chrome**

5.) **Return to the same page later and the note will be there**

---

**Bonus:**

In addition to saving notes it might also be useful to know if you've visited a link and how long ago you did (uses your history).

1.) **Install [Link Status Redux](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-status-redux/)**

[image: install link status redux]

2.) **Restart Firefox**

3.) **Hover over a visited link**

[image: visited link]

Comment: I can't believe I haven't found those... Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks! (You'll have to wait a few hours for the bounty)

Comment: You're very welcome! I also added a mention for another extension you might find useful.

Comment: This is perfect! I am going to start looking for a new place to stay after a month, and I was looking for something like this!

Answer (score 0):

If the ads are presented as links, visited links are normally visually distinct from
unvisited ones. If they are not so on that website, you can override its .CSS
to make them distinct.

You can also modify the HTML presented by the website by using your own user script.

In Firefox, the tool to use is the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) extension.
In Google Chrome, Greasemonkey scripts work natively.

Lots of information and tutorials can be found on the internet for writing Greasemonkey scripts.

This is as far as I can go without knowing more about this website that you describe
and how the ads are presented in HTML/CSS.

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear: I would also like to write: "Interesting", (or something similar) as it's not something I buy when I see the ad the first time (it's real estate). Therefore it's not enough to know I've visited the ad before.

Comment: With Greasemonkey you can do anything at all that you like. The only problem would be where to stock the "[Not] Interesting" tags. Probably some cloud-storage service can do the job.